# immediately set the setting defined in setting charm metro app

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-runtime

Hi there I'am quite new to c# and WPF and was wondering if anyone could help me with a problem that I am currently having. I'm looking for a way to immediately set the settings defined by the elements in the Settings charm.

For example in Mail when i click Account on Setting Panel and then check or uncheck checkbox for mail organization. I hope to be clear.

I tried the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh872190.aspx but I do not think this is what I ask (it shows only how to draw the controls in setting charm). Someone has some examples or can explain how i can do that? tnx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One of the ways:

Listen for change events of your controls in settings charm or use binding to detect changes.
Call update (your view or controls that depends on this option) function as some option change, right in code where you detect changes in this option. Keep settings values in the App object (App.xaml.cs) to access them at the all pages.

Also you can use MVVM pattern too, but if you new in coding, it can be a bit hard for start. However it's the better way.